# Error inserting data: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inserting a record to a MySQL table after the successful establishment of connection fails. I'm currently stuck with an issue inserting a record into MySQL table although the connection to the DB establishes perfectly. The line that is throwing the error is `const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE isrc = ?', [trackData.isrc]);` placed in the JS file mysql-utils.js

index.js contents:

```
const express = require('express') // Get object of express npm module
const trackSaveRouter = require('./routers/track-save')

const app = express() // Instantiate Express server
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

app.use(express.json()) // Parse incoming body into JSON
app.use(trackSaveRouter)


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up and running on: ' + port)
})
```

track-save.js contents

```
const express = require('express')
const Track = require('../models/track')
const router = new express.Router()
const request = require('request'); // "Request" library
const { connectToMySQL, closeMySQLConnection } = require('../db/mysql-connection')
const { insertData } = require('../utils/mysql-utils');

router.post('/track/save', async (req,res) => { // Route handler
  try {
    // Connect to MySQL
    await connectToMySQL();

    const isrc = req.body.isrc   // Retrieve isrc
    console.log('isrc:', isrc)
    const clientID = 'Hidden' // Your client id
    const clientSecret = 'Hidden' // Your secret

    var authOptions = { // Application requests authorization
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(clientID + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64'))
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, async function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        var token = body.access_token;
        var options = { // USVT10300001, USEE10001992, GBAYE0601498, USWB11403680, GBAYE0601477
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=isrc:' + isrc + '&type=track',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
          },
          json: true
        };
        request.get(options, async function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('Unable to fetch Track data!')
            return
          }

          if (!body.tracks.items || body.tracks.items.length === 0) { 
            console.log('Track data unavailable for ISRC: !' + isrc)
            return
          }

          //console.log(body.tracks.items)
          //process.exit() 
          let musicTrack, trackWithHighPopularity, spotifyImageUri, title, artistNames = [] // In case multiple tracks are returned
          body.tracks.items.forEach((e, index) => {
            //console.log(e.popularity)
            if (index === 0) {
              trackWithHighPopularity = e
              return
            }
            // From second iteration onwards
            if (e.popularity > trackWithHighPopularity.popularity) {
              trackWithHighPopularity = e
            }
          })

          musicTrack = trackWithHighPopularity
          //console.log(musicTrack.album.images)
          //process.exit();
          spotifyImageUri = musicTrack.album.images[0].url // Get spotify image URI
          // console.log(spotifyImageUri)
          title = musicTrack.name // Get Title
          // console.log(title)
          //console.log(musicTrack.artists)
          musicTrack.album.artists.forEach((e)=>{
            artistNames.push(e.name)
          })
          // Convert array into a comma-separated string.
          artistNamesString = artistNames.join(', ')
          //console.log(artistNamesString)
          // Call the insertData function with the trackData parameter
          await insertData({ // Write metadata to DB
            isrc,
            title,
            artistNamesString,
            spotifyImageUri
          })

          console.log('Data inserted successfully');

          // Close MySQL connection after inserting Data
          await closeMySQLConnection();
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing track:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

mysql-connection.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise'); // Using promise-based version

const dbConfig = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'spotify_web_server_api',
};

let connection;

async function connectToMySQL() {
  try {
    connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
    if (connection) {
      console.log('Connected to MySQL');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', error.message);
  }
}

async function closeMySQLConnection() {
  try {
    if (connection) {
      await connection.end();
      console.log('Closed MySQL connection');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error closing MySQL connection:', error.message);
  }
}

module.exports = { connection, connectToMySQL, closeMySQLConnection };
```

mysql-utils.js contents

```
const { connection } = require('../db/mysql-connection');

async function insertData(trackData) {
  try {
    // Check if a record with the given 'isrc' value already exists
    const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE isrc = ?', [trackData.isrc]);

    if (rows.length > 0) {
      // If a matching record is found, return an error
      throw new Error('Record with the same isrc ' + trackData.isrc + ' already exists');
    }

    // If no matching record is found, insert the data
    await connection.execute('INSERT INTO tracks SET ?', trackData);

    console.log('Data inserted successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error inserting data:', error.message);
  }
}

module.exports = { insertData };
```

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue if you have credentials for a Spotify developer account.

1. Run the Express server by running "node index.js"
2. Run your MySQL server
3. In your postman app, enter the endpoint http://localhost:4000/track/save, by passing the JSON parameter
   {
   "isrc":"GBAYE0601477"
   }
4. In the CLI, you should see the error saying "Error inserting data: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')"

I tried to pass `connection` object when calling `insertData()`, but that still gave the same error. Tried to change `let` to `var`. That also didn't help

Comment: You're assigning to `module.exports` in `mysql-connection.js` before `connectToMySQL()` has been called, so `connection` is undefined and you're exporting that undefined valiue.

Comment: Are you suggesting I pass `connection` object from within connectToMySQL() when this function is called?

Comment: Barmar, please help me fix this. I tried to pass connection object but received an error "Bind parameters must be array if namedPlaceholders parameter is not enabled"

Comment: Do it like in `track-save.js`. You need to call `await connectToMySQL();` before trying to use `connection`.